# Finding $|\varnothing\setminus B|$ and $|B\times\varnothing|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose I have $B=\{w,x\}$. I am asked to find $|\varnothing\setminus B|$ and $|B\times\varnothing|$.

Since $\varnothing$ is the *empty* set, I would imagine $\varnothing-B=\varnothing$. Thus, I would figure $|\varnothing\setminus B|=1$. Is this right?

What about for $|B\times\varnothing|$? Is that even possible to compute or is it undefined? I'd have $\{w,x\}\times\{\}$. So would the ordered pairs be $(w,)$ and $(x,)$? That doesn't really seem to make sense.

**Edit:** Based on an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51401/how-do-the-sets-emptyset-times-b-a-times-emptyset-emptyset-times-em), it would seem that $|B\times\varnothing|=|\varnothing|=1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Wait, how is $|\varnothing|=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $$|\varnothing\setminus B|=1,$$ Then there exist $$x\in\varnothing$$ such that $$x\not\in B.$$

Answer (score 1):

The size of $\emptyset$ is defined to be $0$. Also $B\times\emptyset=\{(x,y):x\in B \wedge y\in \emptyset\}=\emptyset$. In this sort of problems do use the definition since it clears your mind.

You don't have to imagine that $\emptyset \setminus B = \emptyset$. In fact, $\emptyset \setminus B = \{x:x\in\emptyset\wedge x \notin B \}$. Is there any $x$ satisfying the conditions to be in the last set I mentioned?

Comment: So you are, in effect, saying that the answer to both of my problems is $|\varnothing|=0$. Is that right?

Comment: @snake yes, you can see it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set)